# SignalR connection pooling

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I have 2 separate ASP.Net sites, one is outward facing serving the UI and the other is a backend API that is only ever accessed by the UI server.

We are using SignalR to push events through the client but these events originate on the backend API so there is a SignalR connection from browser -> UI Server and another from UI Server -> Backend API.

Currently each client that connects SignalR from the browser causing a new connection to be made to the backend API. This means that we have a lot of connections for the same hubs through between the same processes.

Is there any way in SignalR to have it pool the connections so they use the same underlying sockets while hiding that abstraction from my code in the SignalR .Net Client?

Comment: You can connect directly to the backend API throw javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is a on a different network and not exposed to the Internet. There are some functions of the intermediary server as well which would be skipped over.